# How to wait for Http answer in TypeScript - Angular 5

Tags: typescript, http, angular5

i want to make a function that returns a token from a server but `http.post()` gets a response after my function returned the token.

How do i wait for `http.post()` before returning the token.

My code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

export class ServerConnectionService{
    constructor( private http : Http) { }
    token : string;
    Login(Password : string, Username : string, ServerRootURL : string) : string
    {
        let url = ServerRootURL + "api/AdminApp/RegisterToken";
        this.http.post(url, { "Username": Username, "Password": Password }).toPromise()
            .then(res => this.token =  res.json())
            .catch(msg => console.log('Error: ' + msg.status + ' ' + msg.statusText))
        return this.token;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can't wait to a asynchronous code and return something from it.As you use promise, you need to use `then`able functions and write the rest logic which is related to the result of it in that `then`able functions. In your case it will be

```
Login(Password : string, Username : string, ServerRootURL : string): Promise<string>  {
      let url = ServerRootURL + "api/AdminApp/RegisterToken";
      return this.http.post(url, { "Username": Username, "Password": Password }).toPromise()
                      .then(res => this.token =  res.json())
                      .catch(msg => console.log('Error: ' + msg.status + ' ' + msg.statusText))
 }
```

and you need to use it like

```
Login('password', 'username', 'http://localhost:8081').then(token => your logic here)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define your `Login()` function as `async`. Then you may `await` your `http.post()` call:

```
public async Login(pass: string, user: string): string {
    ...
    let response: Response = await this.http.post(url, data).toPromise();
    return response.json();
}
```

Note that calling `Login()` will also need to be `await`ed.

```
let token = await Login("foo", "bar");
```

Comment: Mention also that `await` must be also in the `async` function